# How to test IME_ACTION_DONE on Genymotion emulator

Tags: android, android-edittext, genymotion

In one of my apps I have an `EditText` that has `android:imeOption="actionDone"` set. I've also set the appropriate `setOnEditorActionListener()`.

```
 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/search_field"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/search_field_hint"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:singleLine="true"/>
```

When testing on a real device everything works great - I enter some text, hit the "Done" button and my action get's triggered.

On Genymotion emulator though (that I really prefer using while development) I can't see the soft-keyboard, thus I can't click the "Done" button to trigger the action.

How do I test if my `imeOption` is set and is working correctly on Genymotion emulator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before opening the emulator press the *preferences* button of the emulator and check the *Use virtual keyboard for text input*. This should do the trick, of course u will need to press on the virtual keyboard.